# is it possible to flag my android app in google play as not available until a certain date?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, developer-console

When I release an iOS app in iTunes Connect I can specify the **availability date**.

*Is there an equivalent on the Google Play Developer Console?*

I wish to release my app today, but the launch is not for some weeks and I don't want anyone to download it before then.

Comment: no you can't do this

Comment: you cant keep it in draft , and later on publish. but it wil not be visible

Comment: thanks for the responses,  
I want to ensure it doesn't hit any snags with release, so what I'm doing is just releasing it to Albania for now, and I'll add the rest of the world on the release date. :)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available only for updates of already published apps
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?rd=1#modes

> Timed publishing is only available for updates, not when publishing an app for the first time.

You can publish some "Coming soon" as a first APK, and the update for exact publishing time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
What you can do is create this check inside your application.

Check this pseudocode:

```
if (today >= releaseDate) {
  startApplication(); // Start activity as you wanted, load layouts etc.
} else {
  showSomeInfoAboutReleaseDate() // Load layout with info. Maybe some counter or just splash screen etc.
}
```

This will allow users to download app but they'll not be able to use it before release date that you set inside your app.

Comment: Interesting idea - thank you.
But also easily circumvented by changing the date on one's phone, no?

Comment: @user1290746 you could get server-side date using web service :)

Comment: Amy - true enough. 
More trouble than it's worth for me for this app right now.
My current plan is to publish now and watch it, then "Unpublish" it as soon as the publication is complete, and then I'll republish it a couple hours before our launch date.

But I'm appreciating the creative thinking and open to more ideas still too. :)